# How to sync drupal event calendar with Outlook Calendar

Tags: php, drupal, synchronization, outlook

i am using drupal events calendar and i am creating events. Now i want to view these events automatically in the Microsoft Outlook calendar when i look into my outlook.

Currently i am exporting the drupal calendar events as calendar.ics files and then importing them in the outlook manually. How can i automate this process?

I am sure that Outlook can import files of format ".ics" and so i am just curious to know how can i import an ics file into my Outlook, or put in other way, how to add events to outlook calendar with php ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- With Outlook 2007, you can subscribe to ical calendar (you just have to provide url to your ics file).
- With Outlook 2003, you can use a plugin to sync with ics file : http://remotecalendars.sourceforge.net/

PS: not a drupal issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... i am using Outlook 2003 and i have installed that plugin... now how can i sync with ics files?

Comment: Sorry, FYI, this solution is not favourable to me, as installing another software or plugin at the client side is not recommended. All users may not do it. Is there any other alternative? I just want to know how to add events to outlook calendar with php. By the way, i have found a sample php script that can generate events as ".ics" files, which can be saved to outlook: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990017/add-events-to-outlook-calendar-with-php-script