# Trying to Add Event to Outlook Calendar but its not working

Tags: php, outlook, calendar, icalendar

`Hi Everything, From the last 2-3 days i have tried many methods to Add Event to my Outlook Calendar, but Its not assigning, I am receiving the email with different layout, means its shows the HTML scripts too. i dont know what i am doing wrong. need your kind help please.

**---- MY PHP CODE -----**

```
$domain = 'dopasi.org';
$from_name = 'FromName'; // From       
$from_address = 'fromEmail@gmail.com'; // From Email 
$to_name = 'ToName';        
$to_address = 'toEmail@dopasi.org';
$startTime = '13/11/2023' . ' ' . '11:00';  
$endTime = '13/11/2023' . ' ' . '12:00';  
$subject = 'Meeting Title';   
$description = 'Meeting Description';    
$location = "TestCity";
        
//Create Email Headers
$mime_boundary = "----Meeting Booking----".MD5(TIME());
        
$headers = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_address.">\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$from_name." <".$from_address.">\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"$mime_boundary\"\n";
$headers .= "Content-class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage\n";
        
        //Create Email Body (HTML)
$message = "--$mime_boundary\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
$message .= "<html>\n";
$message .= "<body>\n";
$message .= '<p>Dear '.$to_name.',</p>';
$message .= '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
$message .= "</body>\n";
$message .= "</html>\n";
$message .= "--$mime_boundary\r\n";
        
$ical = 'BEGIN:VCALENDAR' . "\r\n" .
        'PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 10.0 MIMEDIR//EN' . "\r\n" .
        'VERSION:2.0' . "\r\n" .
        'METHOD:REQUEST' . "\r\n" .
        'BEGIN:VTIMEZONE' . "\r\n" .
        'TZID:Asia/Karachi' . "\r\n" .
        'BEGIN:STANDARD' . "\r\n" .
        'DTSTART:20231114T020000' . "\r\n" .
        'RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=11' . "\r\n" .
        'TZOFFSETFROM:-0400' . "\r\n" .
        'TZOFFSETTO:-0500' . "\r\n" .
        'TZNAME:EST' . "\r\n" .
        'END:STANDARD' . "\r\n" .
        'BEGIN:DAYLIGHT' . "\r\n" .
        'DTSTART:20231114T020000' . "\r\n" .
        'RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=2SU;BYMONTH=3' . "\r\n" .
        'TZOFFSETFROM:-0500' . "\r\n" .
        'TZOFFSETTO:-0400' . "\r\n" .
        'TZNAME:EDST' . "\r\n" .
        'END:DAYLIGHT' . "\r\n" .
        'END:VTIMEZONE' . "\r\n" .  
        'BEGIN:VEVENT' . "\r\n" .
        'ORGANIZER;CN="'.$from_name.'":MAILTO:'.$from_address. "\r\n" .
        'ATTENDEE;CN="'.$to_name.'";ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:'.$to_address. "\r\n" .
        'LAST-MODIFIED:' . date("Ymd\TGis") . "\r\n" .
        'UID:'.date("Ymd\TGis", strtotime($startTime)).rand()."@".$domain."\r\n" .
        'DTSTAMP:'.date("Ymd\TGis"). "\r\n" .
        'DTSTART;TZID="Asia/Karachi":'.date("Ymd\THis", strtotime($startTime)). "\r\n" .
        'DTEND;TZID="Asia/Karachi":'.date("Ymd\THis", strtotime($endTime)). "\r\n" .
        'TRANSP:OPAQUE'. "\r\n" .
        'SEQUENCE:1'. "\r\n" .
        'SUMMARY:' . $subject . "\r\n" .
        'LOCATION:' . $location . "\r\n" .
        'CLASS:PUBLIC'. "\r\n" .
        'PRIORITY:5'. "\r\n" .
        'BEGIN:VALARM' . "\r\n" .
        'TRIGGER:-PT15M' . "\r\n" .
        'ACTION:DISPLAY' . "\r\n" .
        'DESCRIPTION:Reminder' . "\r\n" .
        'END:VALARM' . "\r\n" .
        'END:VEVENT'. "\r\n" .
        'END:VCALENDAR'. "\r\n";
        $message .= 'Content-Type: text/calendar;name="meeting.ics";method=REQUEST'."\n";
        $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
$message .= $ical;
        
$mailsent = mail($to_address, $subject, $message, $headers);
echo ($mailsent) ? 'Success' : 'Failed';
```

**Result- Email Received**

```
`------Meeting Booking----fcf0f13b816a3795030bbfc724382b1d
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
<html>
<body>
<p>Dear ToName,</p><p>Meeting Description</p></body> </html> ------Meeting Booking----fcf0f13b816a3795030bbfc724382b1d
Content-Type: text/calendar; name="meeting.ics";method=REQUEST
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 10.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID: Asia/Karachi
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:20231114T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=11
TZOFFSETFROM:-0400
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
TZNAME:EST
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:20231114T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=2SU;BYMONTH=3
TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
TZOFFSETTO:-0400
TZNAME:EDST
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
ORGANIZER;CN="fromName":MAILTO:fromEmail@gmail.com
ATTENDEE;CN="toName";ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:toEmail#gmail.com
LAST-MODIFIED:20231114T112000
UID:19700101T500002143262541@mydomain.com
DTSTAMP:20231114T112000
DTSTART;TZID="Asia/Karachi":19700101T050000
DTEND;TZID="Asia/Karachi":19700101T050000
TRANSP:OPAQUE
SEQUENCE:1
SUMMARY: Meeting Title
LOCATION: TestCity
CLASS:PUBLIC
PRIORITY:5
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION: Reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR`
```

------------------ This is what i received in email and Event is not added in Calendar ----------------`

Comment: If you want to send email attachments I strongly suggest using something like phpmailer to send the emails then you don't have to figure it out yourself, it can be a very fiddly job to get right. With a library they have done all the hard work for you and you can just call a function to attach a file, providing the content without needing to worry about the fine details of the email syntax

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990017/add-events-to-outlook-calendar-with-php-script

Answer (score 0):

When sending to Outlook, make sure your message has a single part of type `text/calendar`. HTML can be added using `X-ALT-DESC` field (with `FMTTYPE` attribute = `text/html`) in your iCal data.