Is it possible to automatically set an event in Outlook calendar from an attached ics file?
I've found numerous questions here with similar goal - to set an Event in Outlook calendar.
Many are very old (some more than 8 years old) so I'm not sure they are relevant anymore, and I've already tried them but they didn't work for me.
What is working for me right now is that I am able to attach an .ics file, however it doesn't add to the calendar, and is only sent as an attachment in the mail, even if I set the mime to be text/calendar
This is how I try to do it:
class SendEmailAndCreateEvent extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct()
    {
        
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('test@example.com', 'Test Mailer')
            ->subject("Creating an Event")
            ->markdown('emails.calendar')
            ->attach(public_path() . '/test.ics', [
                'as' => 'calendar.ics',   
                'mime' => 'text/calendar'            
            ]);
    }

I also read I might need to use the Graph API, but I am not sure now because I've seen that it can be done via .ics.  Could my problem be solved by using the Graph API?

Yes Graph API can create calendar events directly. But you need permission to the Azure tenant of the user whose calendar it is. They can grant you it using Oauth if that's the approach you want to take. Depends on your scenario.

I'm not aware that attaching an ics to a mail can automatically create a calendar event in the mailboxes calendar...otherwise spammers would have great fun adding random meetings to everyone's calendars all day long. Where did you read thar, exactly? The user should always have the choice about what goes into their calendar.

@ADyson thank you, makes sense. I contacted the sysadmin for more help. I've seen posts like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990017/add-events-to-outlook-calendar-with-php-script, but I guess I misunderstood it

For one thing all the answers there are quite old, and security etc has improved a lot in that time. But mainly they just show how to send an email with an ics. none of them say explicitly it will automate adding the item to the calendar, except for one which says it will work if you send it as an email and the from address is the same email address as the account setup in Outlook...it doesn't sound like that's your situation here? And even then it's old advice and I don't know if it would still work
